# Given integers $a$ and $b > 0$, show that there exists a unique integer -

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given integers $a$ and $b > 0$, show that there exists a unique integer $r$ with $0\le r\lt b$ satisfying  $a = \left\lfloor \dfrac{a}{b} \right\rfloor b + r$

---

I am familiar with the Euclidean algorithm where $q$ is an integer, but the greatest integer function here is throwing me off. Any help/hints ?

Comment: Note that $q=\left[{a\over b}\right]$ follows from the standard Euclidean division, since $0\le r < b$, you just look at the set

$$\{a-kb : k\in\Bbb Z\}\subseteq\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$$

and show if $r$ is the minimal element, it (1) satisfies the inequality and (2) necessarily the $k$ you come up with is the usual $q$ as above.

Comment: Hint: $$r=a\mod b$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q=\left\lfloor \frac{a}{b}\right\rfloor$. Then by the definition of the "greatest integer" function, we have
$$q\le \frac{a}{b}\lt q+1.\tag{1}$$
Since $a=\frac{a}{b}\cdot b$ and $b$ is positive, it follows that
$$qb\le a \lt qb+b.\tag{2}$$
Thus $0\le a-qb\lt b$. Set $a-qb$ equal to $r$. The fact that $0\le r\lt b$ follows from the Inequalities (2).

The uniqueness is left to you!

Comment: This looks exactly same as euclidian algorithm xD  thank you :D

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, it is the same as the result often called the *Division Algorithm*. The notation is a little different, that's all. Note that the result usually called the *Euclidean Algorithm* is something else, it has to do with the gcd. The proof through the greatest integer function cheats a tiny bit, since it *assumes* the existence of $\lfloor x\rfloor$.